# Swap function potential missed optimization? (gcc)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, swap, micro-optimization

I wrote this swap function in Linux x86-64 assembly.

```
swap: ; written by me
    mov al, byte [rdi]
    xchg byte [rsi], al
    mov byte [rdi], al
    ret
```

Out of curiosity, I also compiled the following C code with -O3

```c
void swap(char *a, char *b) {
  char temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

used objconv on it to get the following assembly.

```
swap:   ; written by GCC -O3
        endbr64                                         ; 0000 _ F3: 0F 1E. FA
        movzx   eax, byte [rdi]                         ; 0004 _ 0F B6. 07
        movzx   edx, byte [rsi]                         ; 0007 _ 0F B6. 16
        mov     byte [rdi], dl                          ; 000A _ 88. 17
        mov     byte [rsi], al                          ; 000C _ 88. 06
        ret                                             ; 000E _ C3
```

What it has done also makes sense, and does the job, but my code is shorter. Is this a missed optimization? If so, how's this missed by GCC?

Comment: Your code is shorter but slower.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why is it slower?

Comment: Because `xchg` automatically implies a `lock` when used with memory operands. Also, writing `al` might cause false dependencies.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Got it. So basically, **for performance**, `xchg` for two registers is totally ok, but is not ok for a memory operand.

Comment: fewer instructions is not always faster, often there are cases where more is faster...memory accesses vs registers, etc...